# jQuery add form select value to $_GET value of remote file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I was seeking help in a previous threat, and the advice lead me in a different direction. As such, the thread died. I've made a lot of progress, and I feel very close to my answer.

I have two files:
Local file: maps.php
Remote file: maps_append.php

maps.php has a form select tag. I need jQuery to get the value of whatever option is select and load the remote URL (maps_append.php) with maps_append.php?cmd=(value)

What I have is:

```
<form method="post" action="maps.php">
    <td colspan="3">
        <select id="cmdview" name="cmd">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="commdata" {if $cmdOn == "commdata"}selected="true"{/if}>Communications</option>
            <option value="contacts" {if $cmdOn == "contacts"}selected="true"{/if}>Contacts</option>
            <option value="enrollment" {if $cmdOn == "enrollment"}selected="true"{/if}>Enrollment</option>
            <option value="all" {if $cmdOn == "all"}selected="true"{/if}>All Schools</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" name="doSwitch" value="Submit" />

    </td>

    <div id="append"></div2>

</form>
```

This is my HTML. My jQuery is:

```
<script>
$('#cmdview').change(function() {
    //alert('Handler for .change() called.');
        var str = "";
            url = "maps_append.php?cmd=str";
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
           });
            $.post( url, { cmdview: str } , 
                function( data ) {
                    var content = $( data );
                $('#append').load(url);
                    })
                    .change();
                        });
</script>
```

The problem is my $_GET value (cmd) is always "str". It won't take the value of my select HTML. I can't figure out the syntax for it to great the select value.

All I need is str to = the value of whatever < . option . > is selected

EDIT::
I'd like to add that I know the $.post isn't needed now that I'm doing a _GET value. But, I don't know how else to format this... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have proper indentation, or else you are going to get lost quickly. I have cleaned up most of your code. You were hard coding "str" in your url instead of concatenating the variable:

```
<script>
$('#cmdview').change(function() {
    //alert('Handler for .change() called.');
    var str = '',
        url = 'maps_append.php?cmd=';
    $('select option:selected').each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + ' ';
    });

    url += str;

    $.post( url, { cmdview: str } , function( data ) {
         var content = $( data );
         $('#append').load(url);
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

Also note that you are first doing a POST request to `maps_append.php` which will have both `$_POST['cmdview']` and `$_POST['cmd']` set to the options you sent, then once that script has returned a response, you make a GET request by using the `load()` method, which will then replace the HTML in `#append`. Not sure why there is that last `change()` at the end.

From what I can tell, it sounds more like you're trying to do something more like this:

```
<script>
$('#cmdview').change(function() {

    var url = 'maps_append.php?cmd=' + $(this).val();

    $.get(url, function(data){
        $('#append').append(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure either. I've just been through tons of versions of this code. This is the closest it has come to working when I do print_r($_GET) as this point. If I knew how to format it correctly, I could get rid of the $.post

Comment: Did you see my alternate solution? I think I've solved a lot of your problems for you in the second solution (but I am also making some assumptions about how it is supposed to work).

Comment: YES!! Andrew, you're awesome! I'm getting the _GET data now! Thank you!!

Comment: For clarification for anyone who may my same problem: Now, thanks to Andrew's code revision:
I went from: [cmd] => ....nothing
to [cmd] => *myvalue*

Comment: my maps_append.php calls a new form. This loads the new <input into maps.php . When I submit, it doesn't submit. 

Any idea why? The value of the select tag submits but the appended input doesn't...

Comment: Do you mean that maps_append.php returns an entire form? Or it only returns an input/select element?

Answer (score 2):

change

```
    url = "maps_append.php?cmd=str";
```

to

```
 url = "maps_append.php?cmd=" + str;
```

Comment: I tried that. In maps.php, I'm doing print_r($_GET);. It says [cmd] => 

.... nothing. The value doesn't get passed.

Comment: For some reason that I don't understand, str is not the value of my select option. :(

Comment: It's still too early at that point `str = ""`, you need to build your url in the `.post()`. `$.post( "maps_append.php?cmd=" + str, { cmdview: str } ,`. Also the `str` is getting passed as the variable `cmdview` so you could access it in the php by `$_POST['cmdview']` and ditch putting it on the url, just have the url be `"maps_append.php"`.

Comment: you should also change
 str += $(this).text() + " ";
to 
 str += $(this).val() + " ";

Comment: @Rusty Could you please give an example? I realize that I am calling str = "" too soon, but I don't know where to call it. I also think that I am not setting my option value to = str anymore. I used to work but doesn't now. 

I know I can delete the entire .post function as I'm now doing a GET value, but when I remove it, I get syntax errors that break everything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you're are trying to accomplish can be resolved with much simpler code. Try replacing your existing JavaScript with this:

```
$(function() {
$('#cmdview').change(function() {
    $('#append').load("maps_append.php?cmd=" + $(this).val());
}).change();
});
```

This code is simply saying, when you change `#cmdview` load the contents of the file `maps_append.php?cmd=` with the value of `#cmdview` appended to the url. This should make it so you can access the value of `#cmdview` in your PHP code with `$_GET['cmd']`.